# Me sale este error que no puedo solucionar:SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, pdo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estuve haciendo un pequeño proyecto y salió este error y no se cual es el problema, he visto como solucionarlo pero nada me sirve.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]s9qr3.png

Comment: Evita el uso de caracteres nacionales en los nombres de las variables. Es decir, sin acentos, a ver si con eso superas el error.

Comment: Muchas gracias bro

Comment: no pongas el codigo como imagen eso generalmente hace mas dificil ayudarte